# Install Magento 2 in AWS with Git

Tags: magento2.3, aws, git

How to install Magento 2 in AWS with git?

I am using linux mint as my local OS.
Now  I would like to install Magento 2 in AWS with git.
So that I can push code to AWS after working on file from
my local machine.

How can I do this ?